# Prior Art US 20130177891 A1

Tags: prior-art-request, video, meta-data, us20130177891, time-stamp

Audio-visual learning system 
US 20130177891 A1
Filing date: July 2, 2012

I am searching for Prior Art on the application listed above. 
Below is prior art that I am aware of.

The claims in patent application "US 20130177891 A1" describe technology that has been publicly available, as an online application, since at least 2005, when Yabla Inc. began offering to the public LoMasTv.Com and clic.yabla.com and ola.yabla.com. (These sites now operating as http://spanish.yabla.com and http://french.yabla.com, aka "Yabla Spanish" and "Yabla French"). Subsequent to 2005 and prior to 2012 other firms have publicly offered similar technology that also matches claims in application US 20130177891 A1, services such as yappr.com, englishcentral.com, papagei.com, and others, some of whom no longer exist.

To employ the use of time stamps and meta data in a database associated with a video as a means of finding "jump to" points for caption based back and forward navigation has been publicly demonstrated in the "Yabla Player" since 2005 — which long-time early customers of Yabla, such the University of Michigan could easily attest to. The idea of being able to search the meta-data and being able to jump to the time stamp associated with that data is not new, and neither is storing the metadata and time stamps separately from the video media itself. The idea of associating a separate set of audio as time stamped metadata is not new, yappr.com has been doing it for years (e.g. a differently pronounced audio presentation of the caption text). The idea of having a dictation mode (a game) wherein the user types in a caption word (or words) and the input is compared to the known correct caption word or words has been in publicly practice by Yabla Inc ("The Yabla Player")since 2005 and, again, was also practiced by other commercial services subsequent to 2005 and before 2012.

A youtube video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3bxKO8cXaHw
dated 08/27/2010 demonstrates the "Yabla Player" in use on the Yabla Inc. owned site "LoMásTv.Com" — and demonstrate many of its features that coincide with the claims of this application.

Further examples of prior art relating to this patent application and its claims are appreciated.

Comment: This application is listed as "Abandoned -- Failure to Respond to an Office Action" as of 06-09-2016.